# Select is missing .ThenInclude EF query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a query that ended up being n^3 so I'm simplifying it. I found a way to write it to only be n^2 but for some reason the `.ThenInclude` property is missing. Is this not the right way to write it?

```
test.Include(t => t.a)
     .Include(t => t.b)
         .ThenInclude(b => b.c)
     .Where(t => Users.Exists(u => u.Id == t.a.Id))
     .Select( t => t.b)
     .ToListAsync()
```

This returns a list of 'b' but b.c is null when I try to access it.

Comment: This isn't EF6. Also, a projection (`Select`) affects which `Includes` are actually effective, see [Ignored Includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes).

Comment: Ah okay so it looks like I have to do 
`t => new b() 
{
 // the rest of b
 C = t.b.uc
}
`

Is there a spread operator like in js where you can do ...b to put everything in and then stick the included object in?

Comment: `(Then)Include` is all there is.

Comment: So the only way would be to rewrite my query with "b" instead test? That's my original query but it's very inefficient.

Comment: Perhaps this is an XY Problem - can you tell us what you are trying to accomplish and maybe we could find a better way?

Comment: You could `ToList` before you `Select`.

Comment: If I ToList before I Select wouldn't that just return one item or would it still be a list of items?

Comment: Oh that gives me an Ienumerable instead of a regular list I think. I can manually stick some of the properties i need into the constructor in the select for now, but that's not really safe.

Comment: I think your answer has been given below. If EF is limiting your performance requirements you could circumvent it and use an actual SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Microsoft docs:

> If you change the query so that it no longer returns instances of the entity type that the query began with, then the include operators are ignored.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

You need to rewrite your query to originally return "b" values.